# How to change the umask when mounting volumes in kubernetes pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes

### Update

Using `fsGroup` in a `SecurityContext` allows the "group" permissions on the final mounting point to be set. So referring to the example below (/mydata/storage/sample/one) the perms for "one" will allow the fsGroup ID write access. However, none of the parent folders: "mydata", "storage", "sample" will have any permissions for that fsGroup. The are owned by `root:root` and have `755` as their permissions.

This is a huge problem if the running processes (`runAsUser` and `runAsGroup`) try to create files/folders in any of the parent paths

### Original Post

When mounting volumes inside pods to containers, the mountpath does not need to exist. And it will be created. However this directories in this path get created with certain umask (i believe it's 0022).

I have set the umask in Dockerfile but it has not made any difference.

Is there a way to change that in the deployment yaml file?

Example (copied from Kubernetes docs)

```
$ cat pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: redis
  namespace: play
spec:
  containers:
  - name: redis
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: redis-storage
      mountPath: /mydata/storage/sample/one
  volumes:
  - name: redis-storage
    emptyDir: {}

$ kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
pod/redis created



$ kubectl get pods -n play --watch
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
redis   1/1     Running   0          67s


$ kubectl exec -it redis -n play bash
root@redis:/data# ls -l /
total 72
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 May 13 20:25 boot
drwxr-xr-x   2 redis redis 4096 Aug 14 14:11 data
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  root   360 Aug 20 04:25 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root  4096 Aug 20 04:25 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 May 13 20:25 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root  4096 Aug 14 14:11 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   3 root  root  4096 Aug 20 04:25 mydata
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 743 root  root     0 Aug 20 04:25 proc
drwx------   1 root  root  4096 Aug 14 14:10 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root  4096 Aug 20 04:25 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root  root     0 Aug 19 21:55 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root  root  4096 Aug 14 14:11 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root  root  4096 Aug 12 00:00 var
root@redis:/data# ls -l /mydata/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 20 04:25 storage
```

Comment: I struggled (for too long now) with exactly the same problem. Has anybody found a sustainable way to have a mount work in a sane way also with write access? My OS uses `umask 0022` and Kubernetes offers just a `fsGroup` that doesn't help with writing inside the mounted dir. Imho, this makes using Docker for development environment too painful and time wasting.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to setup `SecurityContext` in kubernetes, Example from the Docs:

> Discretionary Access Control: Permission to access an object, like a
>   file, is based on user ID (UID) and group ID (GID).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: security-context-demo
spec:
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: 1000
    runAsGroup: 3000
    fsGroup: 2000
  volumes:
  - name: sec-ctx-vol
    emptyDir: {}
  containers:
  - name: sec-ctx-demo
    image: busybox
    command: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 1h" ]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: sec-ctx-vol
      mountPath: /data/demo
    securityContext:
      allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
```

continue [reading](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

Comment: While the fsGroup addresses the permissions on the final destination (like demo folder in your example) it will not solve the problem on all the preceding folders. I will edit my original post to elaborate.

Comment: Ideally there should be a `securityContext.fsUser`... :(  Alternative is to `chmod` all the files into the entrypoint (that of course highly sucks).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with `mkdir` itself and is due to the `umask` as you mentioned. In the [mkdir spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkdir.html) it's specified that when you use the `-p` flag `chmod` is only called on the full filepath after all the intermediate directories are created.

The Kubernetes [empty dir implementation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/0e8ef9c353092b4c921429a212ebb4c780f83715/pkg/volume/emptydir/empty_dir.go#L442-L469) follows this same logic, calling `os.MkdirAll` which will be impacted by the umask, and then running `os.Chmod` on the full directory path.

This comment in the Kubernetes source is helpful:

> If the permissions on the created directory are wrong, the kubelet is probably running with a umask set.  In order to avoid clearing the umask for the entire process or locking the thread, clearing the umask, creating the dir, restoring the umask, and unlocking the thread, we do a chmod to set the specific bits we need.

So it looks like this implementation was trying to work around not wanting to change the umask of the running process.

I'm not sure what would control the umask on the kubelet process, or if there's any better solution to this problem!