# How are kubernetes secrets mounted?

Tags: kubernetes

### Update

Apparenlty this behavior is caused by `ServiceAccount`:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#service-account-admission-controller

Which uses something called an `AdmissionController`. I guess what I'm looking for is one of the following:

- Find a setting in `AdmissionController` which skips the secrets mount for a given container (initContainer) in my case
- Find an implementation of `AdmissionController` which has this flexibility
- Change the location of secrets from /var/run/secrets to somewhere else

### Original

I have an initContainer which is a part of a pod a part of statefulset. I am mounting some straight forward volumes (so I can create paths/permissions before my app container starts). However as soon as I check the file system, I see a nested path with what seems to be kubernetes secrets.

How did this get mounted? Is this our own doing? Why this path? Can I stop the secrets from being mounted? Can i change the mount path?

```
$ kubectl logs nmnode-0-0 -n test -c prep-hadoop-paths
drwxrwsrwt 4 root root 80 Aug 21 03:52 /run
/run:
total 0
drwxrwsr-x 2 1000 root 40 Aug 21 03:52 configmaps
drwxr-sr-x 3 root root 60 Aug 21 03:52 secrets

/run/configmaps:
total 0

/run/secrets:
total 0
drwxr-sr-x 3 root root 60 Aug 21 03:52 kubernetes.io

/run/secrets/kubernetes.io:
total 0
drwxrwsrwt 3 root root 140 Aug 21 03:51 serviceaccount

/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Aug 21 03:51 ca.crt -> ..data/ca.crt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Aug 21 03:51 namespace -> ..data/namespace
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Aug 21 03:51 token -> ..data/token
```

```
      initContainers:
      - command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - umask 002; ls -ld /run; ls -lR /run; mkdir -p /var/run/secrets/credentials
          ; mkdir -p /var/opt/hdfs ; mkdir -p /var/run/configmaps ; mkdir -p /var/run/secrets/certificates
          ; ls -lR /var;
        image: ubuntu:16.04
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: prep-hadoop-paths
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/opt
          name: data
          subPath: hadoop/var/opt
        - mountPath: /var/log
          name: logs
          subPath: hadoop
        - mountPath: /var/run
          name: var-run
          subPath: hadoop
```

As you can see from the initContainer spec, there is nowhere that I specify or require any secrets to be mounted. However they show up regardless

The following is the volumes listing for the pod.

```
      volumes:
      - name: mssql-master-pool-secret
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: mssql-master-pool-secret
      - name: controller-internal-secret
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: controller-internal-secret
      - emptyDir:
          medium: Memory
        name: var-run
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: mssql-hadoop-storage-0-configmap
        name: hadoop-config-volume
      - name: nmnode-0-agent-secret
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: nmnode-0-agent-secret
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: cluster-configmap
        name: cluster-config-volume
```

If you need more parts of the yaml please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You are on a right way, as [Admission controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/) is the main contributor for implementing various features via Kubernetes API. As you mentioned above [Service Account](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#service-account-admission-controller) is also propagated with some admission features in Kubernetes cluster, initially bounded to the particular admission plugin called `ServiceAccount`.

According to the official Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#how-do-i-turn-on-an-admission-controller), there are special flags`--enable-admission-plugins` and `--disable-admission-plugins` included in `kube-apiserver` [configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) that can be used to enable or disable admission plugins respectively.

By default, `ServiceAccount` admission controller plugin is enabled like described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#which-plugins-are-enabled-by-default). Besides other actions, this plugin mounts volume with token data and CA certificate into the each Pod across K8s cluster for [authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) to the apiserver purposes.

In order to deactivate `ServiceAccount` admission plugin, you can inject `--disable-admission-plugins=ServiceAccount` into the `kube-apiserver` configuration.

Otherwise, if you want to

> Change the location of secrets from /var/run/secrets to somewhere else

This is [where](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#service-account-admission-controller) you can change the path to whatever you want

Comment: Thank you but that's not the answer i was looking for. Those settings are at the pod level. However I wanted to disable for only one container.

Comment: I don't think it's feasible as token data is propagated through all containers in the pod.

Comment: @JeffSaremi there's an update with a link to the code where the path is hard-coded, in case you find it useful.

Comment: I am looking at the link. It tells me where the location is but doesn't tell me how I can change it. May be i'm reading the wrong part.: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#service-account-admission-controller

`It adds a volumeSource to each container of the pod mounted at /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that every pod runs under the context of a service account. That secret that got mounted is the service account's token. Is there a reason why you don't want that to happen?

Comment: it's related to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566773/how-to-change-the-umask-when-mounting-volumes-in-kubernetes-pods

When the mount path is created all intermediate folders become inaccessible. The purpose for the initContainer is to create all these paths before any deeply nested mounting happens

Answer (score 0):

> How did this get mounted?

The [Service Account Admission Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/#service-account-admission-controller) mounted it for you.

> Is this our own doing?

No.

> Why this path?

Because the Kubernetes developers said so? I'm honestly not sure.

> Can I stop the secrets from being mounted?

Yes, since Kubernetes 1.6 you can disable this mounting [at either the Service Account or Pod level.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#use-the-default-service-account-to-access-the-api-server)

```yaml
# a ServiceAccount manifest
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: build-robot
automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

```yaml
# or in a Pod
# the Pod overrides the Service Account on conflict
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-pod
spec:
  serviceAccountName: build-robot
  automountServiceAccountToken: false
```

> Can i change the mount path?

You could try disabling automatic mounting as above, and then manually mount the Secret in the Pod spec:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mypod
    image: redis
    volumeMounts:
    - name: foo
      mountPath: "/etc/foo"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: foo
    secret:
      secretName: your-sa-token-secret
```