# Where does Kubernetes mount service account secrets?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

When a Pod is created, it is always assigned to some Service Account - either `default` or some other account as specified.

[The documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) implies that the API credentials for the Service Account will be automatically mounted unless otherwise specified:

> In version 1.6+, you can opt out of automounting API credentials for a service account by setting `automountServiceAccountToken: false` on the service account [...]
>
> In version 1.6+, you can also opt out of automounting API credentials for a particular pod [...]

However, I'm not sure where these secrets are mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are mounted in `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount`. The API token for the Service Account is available as `token` (i.e. `/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token`), and so on for the rest of the Service Account's associated Secret.

This is described in ["Accessing Clusters"](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) in the official documentation.

Comment: Found the answer while searching for duplicates in a similar, but not identical question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57596808/3551604